# a black line at the top of the screen appears for a long time

Tags: wifi, internet

I'm using the Hera OS on an HP laptop with RAM 4, it's been 2 years since I started using it very well, but now when I turn it on, a black line at the top of the screen appears for a long time, and causes the connection to the internet to be hampered by waiting for this long black line to activate. maybe someone can help me to solve this problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include a picture of that black line? I can’t think of what might be on the screen that also blocks a wireless network connection 

Comment: sorry if it's a little confusing, I mean the black line at the top of the screen that says applications, date, time, wifi indicator, volume, power. they are all one line on the same black line from left to right screen. All of this writing takes 5 minutes to be active when the laptop is turned on, after this black line is alive, internet access can be activated, the question is, how to speed up the process of this black line can be activated immediately when the laptop is turned on?